# Character Driver Unload Fails

Tags: driver, linux-device-driver

I was looking for an `inbuilt` character driver in Linux, I found the relevant driver in the device (`/dev`) list, The character device is with `Major number` 4 (`tty`), but I'm unable to unload that character driver, I tried using following command

```
rmmod Modulet1
```

But when I try this it gives me an error:

> Error: Module Modulet1 is not currently loaded

Could someone assist me with this issue?

I was also looking for associated driver code for this module; does anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: There are no drivers in the /dev. Check `lsmod` output for your driver.

Comment: I'm looking for driver loaded by OS not for a dynamic loadable module, presently my /proc/modules is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not unload a built-in module. Built in modules are compiled along with the kernel and loaded on kernel boot up. Only loadable module can be `insmod`ed and `rmmod`ed.
Also, `lsmod` doesn't show you the in-built modules.

---

For this particular driver, look into this file: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/tty_io.c

Before you go through that code, you might want to look into the `tty` driver structure: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/5896

Comment: I want to search for source code of the module.. How can I find the source file?

Comment: Is it generic driver in linux kernel? what is the name of the module ?

Comment: Its loaded with Major number 4, Name is ttyS1

Comment: Okay.. here's what I would do if I were you, this is the file that lists the `MAJOR_NOS`: `http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/linux/major.h#L18`. Search for the identifier associated with this number. And find the source.

Comment: One more thing I wanted to know is, is there any way we can disable loading of particular major minor combination module from loading which is built-in module?

Comment: Yes. Two options: **1.** Open the `.config`: `vim .config`, search for the particular driver and disable it. **2.** `make menuconfig` from source root folder, and search the device and remove `*`  symbol in front of its name.

Comment: How can I search for a drive with a major number 4 and minor number 60 ??

Comment: Ok. this is not straightforward. You will have to search in `.config` for `ttyS`. And then all the matching symbols that you find, grep them in the linux source and verify if this symbol belongs to this particular driver that you wish to disable.

Comment: Thanks @brokenfoot, but I couldn't locate .config file?

Comment: Are you not compiling your kernel? do a `cp arch/<arch>/config/<config file> .config` from the root of your kernel source.